# Converting a .java file to a .txt document

Tags: java, text

I am trying to figure out how to load a .java doc and out put it into a text document...

What needs to be done:

> Write a program that opens a Java source file, adds line numbers, and
>   saves the result in a new file. Line numbers are numbers which
>   indicate the different lines of a source file, they are useful when
>   trying to draw someone's attention to a particular line (e.g.,
>   "there's a bug on line 4"). Your program should prompt the user to
>   enter a filename, open it, and then save each line to an output fix
>   with the line numbers prepended to the beginning of each line.
>   Afterward, display the name of the output file. The name of the output
>   file should based on the input file with the '.' replaced by a '_',
>   and ".txt" added to the end. (Hint: if you are using a PrintWriter
>   object called pw to save the text file, then the line
>   "pw.printf("%03d", x);" will display an integer x padded to three
>   digits with leading zeros.)

The text.java needs to output into the text document with numbered lines such as:

001 public class dogHouse {

002 public static void main (String[] args) {

003 and so on...

004

```
import java.io.*;

    public class dogHouse {
        public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

            // The name of the file to open.
            String fileName = "test.java";

            // This will reference one line at a time
            String line = null;

            try {
                // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
                FileReader fileReader = 
                    new FileReader(fileName);

                // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                    new BufferedReader(fileReader);

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }   

                // Always close files.
                bufferedReader.close();         
            }

            // The name of the file to open.
            finally {
                // Assume default encoding.
                FileWriter fileWriter =
                    new FileWriter(fileName);

                // Always wrap FileWriter in BufferedWriter.
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter =
                    new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                // Note that write() does not automatically
                // append a newline character.
                bufferedWriter.write("Hello there,");
                // Always close files.
                bufferedWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print and count the `line`(s) as you read them. You also need to differentiate between your output file and your input file. And, I would prefer to use [`try-with-resources` Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Something like,

```
String fileName = "test.java";
String outputFileName = String.format("%s.txt", fileName.replace('.', '_'));
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFileName))) {
    int count = 1;
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        pw.printf("%03d %s%n", count, line);
        count++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```